# IIB - Get DOM Node from aggregated Message

Tags: java, dom, jaxb, messagebroker

I'm currently using IBM Integration Bus v9 and I'm trying to get the DOM Node (org.w3c.dom.Node) from an aggregated message to unmarshall it into a Java Object.

In the first version of my flow, I was calling just one Web Service synchronously and, from a Java Compute Node, I was getting the DOM Document directly from the MbMessage and was unmarshalling the following way ([source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac49011_.htm%23ac49011_)):

```
MbMessage inMessage = inAssembly.getMessage();
JAXBElement<BefpDocData> inMsgJavaObj = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(inMessage.getDOMDocument(), BefpDocData.class);
BefpDocData data = inMsgJavaObj.getValue();
```

The second version of my flow now calls two Web Services asynchronously and aggregate them with an AggregateReply node. In this case, I'm trying this way:

```
MbMessage inMessage = inAssembly.getMessage();
MbElement comIbmAggregateReplyBody = inMessage.getRootElement().getFirstElementByPath("/ComIbmAggregateReplyBody");
MbElement docGenBefa = comIbmAggregateReplyBody.getFirstElementByPath("/ComIbmAggregateReplyBody/DocGenBefa");
MbElement docGenBefaXML = docGenBefa.getLastChild();
Node docGenBefaNode = docGenBefaXML.getDOMNode();
JAXBElement<BefpDocData> inMsgJavaObj = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(docGenBefaNode, BefpDocData.class);
BefpDocData data = inMsgJavaObj.getValue();
```

My problem ist that the getDomNode always returns null despite the fact that the docGenBefaXML points on the XMLNSC part of the message. I tried to call the getDomNode method on various elements of the tree structure and it always returns null.

The structure of an aggregated message is described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac12300_.htm#ac12300_com).

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Not sure. One theory ( and it's just a theory ) is that the getDOMNode() function does not work with aggregated messages. Might be worth checking the docs for getDOMNode(). If nothing comes up, open a PMR and ask IBM.

Comment: Have you tried navigating to the reply root elements in DOM? That might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for both comments, but I had to go one step deeper in the structure (down to the *message body content*) and it worked. But surprisingly, when I tried to display the node object in the debugger, it was also displayed as null.

In this case, if someone has to do the same, here is my code:

```
MbMessage inMessage = inAssembly.getMessage();
MbElement comIbmAggregateReplyBody = inMessage.getRootElement().getFirstElementByPath("/ComIbmAggregateReplyBody");
MbElement docGenBefa = comIbmAggregateReplyBody.getFirstElementByPath("/ComIbmAggregateReplyBody/DocGenBefa");
MbElement docGenBefaXML = docGenBefa.getLastChild();
MbElement docGenBefbDocData = docGenBefaXML.getLastChild();
Node docGenBefaNode = docGenBefbDocData.getDOMNode();
JAXBElement<BefpDocData> inMsgJavaObj = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(docGenBefaNode, BefpDocData.class);
BefpDocData data = inMsgJavaObj.getValue();
```